# Quero fazer uma função que receba um parâmetro n e que me retorne o valor da soma de todos os termos de 1 ate n

Tags: javascript

Eu fiz isso, mas não está funcionando:

```
function a(n) {
    for (var contador = 0; contador <= n; contador++) {
        var soma = soma + contador;
        return soma;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você se esqueceu de retornar a soma fora do laço de repetição. Você deveria declarar a variável fora do laço e inteirar sobre ela, como fiz abaixo. Existem outras formas de se fazer isso, mas como você pediu, como coloquei, funciona perfeitamente.

```js
function a(n) {
  var soma = 0;
  for (var contador = 0; contador <= n; contador++) {
    var soma = soma + contador;
  }
  return soma;
}

console.log(a(5))
// Saída: 15
```